# How to hide NaN (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I'm learning loops in JavaScript and **I'd like to get how to hide all text strings from output.**

When alert of skipping was inside @for operator there was no NaN values in output, but it was shown 2 times undesirable alerts, that's why I moved alert block out of @for loop, and now I got another issue - shows all strings...
all values (6) from array..

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Made function calc degCent
function convertToCentigrade(degFahren)
{
    var degCent;
    degCent = 5/9 * (degFahren - 32);
    return degCent
}

// Created array with data
var degFahren = new Array(212, 32, -459.15, "Huy", 34, 50, "naxxx");

//Create var array degCent
var degCent = new Array ();
//Create Counter
var loopCounter;
//Create loop 

if (isNaN(degFahren))
{ 
    alert ("You have text parameters that will be skipped ");
} 

for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <=6; loopCounter++)
{   
    // Calc degCent via function 
    degCent[loopCounter] = convertToCentigrade(degFahren[loopCounter]);

    document.write ("Value " + loopCounter + " was " + degFahren[loopCounter] + " degrees Fahrenheit");
    document.write (" which is " + degCent[loopCounter] +  " degrees centigrade<br />");
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop you can skip strings using `typeof`:

```
for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <=6; loopCounter++)
  {   
   if (typeof(degCent[loopCounter]) != 'number') continue;

   // Calc degCent via function
   degCent[loopCounter] = convertToCentigrade(degFahren[loopCounter]);


   document.write ("Value " + loopCounter + " was " + degFahren[loopCounter] + " degrees Fahrenheit");
   document.write (" which is " + degCent[loopCounter] +  " degrees centigrade<br />");

  }
```

Comment: I see.. we have to write if (typeof(degFahren[loopCounter]) != 'number') continue;

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if(parseInt(degCent[loopCounter]) != 'NaN') {}`

or

`if (typeof(degFahren[loopCounter]) != 'number')`

To skip the strings