# Couple of questions about code that hides text strings from output

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement

Hello I started learning JavaScript and esterday I asked to help me hide NaN strings of array from output. Some guys helped me.. But I got new questions.

[Here the link to answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964544/how-to-hide-nan-javascript/49965056#49965056)

1. For this code,

   `if (typeof(degFahren[loopCounter]) === 'string')  continue;`

What's happening in there? As I can see If degFahren equal to text string, script will go ahead, but it works another way around and handle numbers for output.

2. For this code

   `if (parseInt(degFahren[loopCounter]) != "NaN")`

It doesnt hide NaN strings at all. Shows all strings from array. Why?

Here block of code that does't work

```
for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <=6; loopCounter++){   

   if (parseInt(degFahren[loopCounter]) != "NaN") 

   degCent[loopCounter] = convertToCentigrade(degFahren[loopCounter]);
   document.write ("Value " + loopCounter + " was " + degFahren[loopCounter] + " degrees Fahrenheit");
   document.write (" which is " + degCent[loopCounter] +  " degrees centigrade<br />");

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are right, but the code fails because you missed the braces. You should add braces after `if` condition

```
for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <=6; loopCounter++){   

   if (parseInt(degFahren[loopCounter]) != "NaN") {

       degCent[loopCounter] = convertToCentigrade(degFahren[loopCounter]);
       document.write ("Value " + loopCounter + " was " + degFahren[loopCounter] + " degrees Fahrenheit");
       document.write (" which is " + degCent[loopCounter] +  " degrees centigrade<br />");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> As I can see If degFahren equal to text string, script will go ahead

`degFahren` is apparently expected to be an *array*. It doesn't test whether `degFahren` is a string, it tests whether the *current element being iterated over* (which is inside the array) is a string.

> It doesnt hide NaN strings at all. Shows all strings from array. Why?

NaN is not a string; it is a primitive value. But NaN !== NaN; you should use the isNaN() function instead.

You should also avoid implicitly creating global variables. It will be easier to read if you abstract the temperatures instead of messing with indicies:

```
for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <=6; loopCounter++){
  const tempF = degFahren[loopCounter];
  if (isNaN(tempF)) continue;
  const tempCentigrade = convertToCentigrade(tempF);
  document.write ("Value " + loopCounter + " was " + tempF + " degrees Fahrenheit");
  document.write (" which is " + tempCentigrade +  " degrees centigrade<br />");
}
```